# How to get the "stats" plugin that comes with a .wordpress.com blog?

Tags: plugins, statistics

On the free version of wordpress, ie the one you setup for free and get hosted at "myblog.wordpress.com", it has a very nice module on the dashboard for tracking statistics. It displays a nice hit-counter graph and shows search engine terms used etc, without any clutter

Is it possible to get this for a self hosted install of wordpress? I can't see it installed by default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not installed by default, but available as plugin from repository: [WordPress.com Stats](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stats/)

Comment: Thanks, any reason why you have to supply an API key to a .wordpress.com blog? What is the reason for this?

Comment: Well, that is how they had set it up. More convenient to link plugin than login/password or whatever. It's not really key from blog, more like from .com login in general. I think you can even sign up for login and API key without creating blog at all.

Comment: @James: You can indeed register on WordPress.com without registering a blog, if you want to use the stats or Akismet services. This key is used to allow you to see stats from multiple sites with one account, and probably to prevent overuse.

Answer (score 1):

The new [Jetpack plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jetpack/) from Automattic (released March 2011) uses the same stats system as the old WordPress.com Stats plugin, it is easier to set up (no API key), and it looks nicer and provides more features. I'd say go with Jetpack.

(I'm the developer of both WordPress.com Stats and the Stats module for Jetpack.)

Comment: Also, I would go with JetPack, since it is more likely to continue to receive future development.